# Difference between filter and choice in camel

Tags: jboss, apache-camel, enterprise-integration

What is the difference between filter and choice in apache Camel?

```
    from("direct:a")
        .choice()
            .when(header("foo").isEqualTo("bar"))
                .to("direct:b")
            .when(header("foo").isEqualTo("cheese"))
                .to("direct:c")
            .otherwise()
                .to("direct:d");
```

Comment: well in short the choice will route the exchange according to the given condition, while the filter removes certain elements from the exchange http://camel.apache.org/content-based-router.html  http://camel.apache.org/message-filter.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In short a filter is like a single java `if` statement, eg

```
if x = 2 {
  ...
}
```

And in Camel:

```
.filter(header("foo").isEqualTo("bar"))
  ...
.end()
```

And choice is like a java `if ... elseif ... elseif ... else` statement,

```
if x = 2 {
  ...
} else if x = 3 {
  ...
}
```

And in Camel:

```
.choice()
  .when(header("foo").isEqualTo("bar"))
    ...
  .when(header("foo").isEqualTo("chese"))
    ...
  .otherwise()
    ....
.end()
```

Note that `otherwise` is optional in the `choice`.

Answer (score 1):

Moreover Choice and filter do same operation, where in Filter have additional property [Exchange](http://people.apache.org/~dkulp/camel/exchange.html) which will states it is filtered or not.

1. Choice is available from version 2.0
2. Filter available from version 2.5